# Did I damage my Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]I was trying to build a Bluetooth controlled car. I was near completing it but what I did wrong was that I connected the 5 V output of L298 motor driver to 5V pin of Arduino where I was supposed to connect it in Vin. My Arduino got heated for a couple of seconds. Knowing that I immediately disconnected. Now serial port doesn't work in my Arduino. The serial port option turned gray. I even tried replacing the ATmega IC but got the same result. What might have happened?

Comment: sounds like you should be able to reprogram it with another ardunio and still use gpio

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds like you fried something.

I can't quite make out what it was you did from your description (I'm sure it makes perfect sense to you with the hardware in front of you), but the symptoms do sound somewhat fatal.

What actually happened depends very much on the Arduino you have - if it's a genuine one or a cheap Chinese clone. Either way the USB circuitry seems to not be functioning. Whether that is because the USB chip (varies depending on if it's a real Arduino [ATMega16U2] or a clone [CH340G]) or one of the voltage regulators is unknown.

You should power the board up normally and test the voltages at the 5V and 3.3V pins. Also if a component is still getting hot you should note which component it is, and that will give more of a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: Ok I did the way you told me to do. The 5V pin is showing 5,03V and 3.3V pin is showing 3.3V exactly and I have powered up board for almost 15 minutes and none of the components got heated up..but what I noticed is that when i press crystal(applying certain force) in arduino D16 000l2 the light in L led turns off. And it also happens when I put my fingers in the soldered portion of 13th pin and below that.

Comment: Precisely which Arduino do you have?

Comment: Arduino uno r3 and I dont know if it is orginal or clone..

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: Ok I live in Nepal. I purchase in local market of my area..

Comment: Can you post a photograph of it?

Comment: yes sure but I dont see any option to upload the photos. Please can u guide me . I have just joined this forum

Comment: Go to edit your question, then insert a picture where the cursor is by clicking the picture icon (a square with two triangles and a dot in it - it's supposed to represent a picture of mountains).

Comment: Thank you sir . Here you go . I have uploaded the picture when the board is normally powered on

Comment: That looks like a fake (clone) Arduino to me. Subtle, and it took close inspection, but the telltale signs are there. The biggest giveaway is the use of the serif font the Chinese fab houses seem to default to where it should be sans-serif (e.g., the word Digital).

Comment: Have you tried the normal things of changing the USB cable, and plugging in to a different USB port?

Comment: Yaa I did all the possible things but none of these worked....I even changed the ic but the same problem exist..I dont know if I shud install a bootloader manually or not..although I was informed that the bootloader was pre installed

Comment: Changing the main IC won't fix it since the problem is with the USB interface and that's a separate chip entirely (the small square one next to the USB socket).

Comment: I get it ..If I recall that chip also got humongously hot at that moment. I guess its probably better if I get a new one. Thanks for your support

Comment: The chip may have survived but just the soldering may have melted and the chip is no longer attached to the board properly. Or the chip may be toast. As you say, buy a new board, it's simplest. With a counterfeit board like that you can never be sure that the components are particularly any good.

Comment: Yes thats definitely right..

Answer (score 0):

You fried it you should ALWAYS double check connections before powering on your arduino but I do suggest doing a normal power up without any connections to see what happens

Comment: I did the normal connection but nothing happens. Neither heating effect nor any other. Just the L led and on led powers on . And I cant use Serial Port . The option is greyed. When I upload any code consider the blink code it tells the com port missing. Is there anything I can do with this board or purchasing a new one shall be better.

Comment: I would prefer you to buy a new original Arduino as it would be quite difficult to repair any hardware issues (which is your issue) which would include soldering replacing and etc° and would be even expensive to buy new parts.

Comment: I guess so..Thanks fotlr the recommendation and help

Answer (score 0):

The ATmega328 on these boards is 5V tolerant on GPIOs so it depends on where exactly you connected the cable.

GND pins, for example, would've been fatal.

Comment: I connected the positive 5V coming from motor driver to 5V pin of arduino and GND for both motor driver and arduino was made common..Everything happened when I connected in 5V pin when I was supposed to connect in Vin pin of arduino

Answer (score 0):

it feel sad to hear that you just fried it up. Every mistakes gives opportunity to learn tons of knowledge.
In this case you supplied 5v supply to 5v output pin. If you've seen the datasheet of  **8-bit AVR Micro-controller ATmega328/P** you'll know that it just possess VCC for 5v supply pin (input) neither an output 5v pin. Its the job of voltage regulator attached next to the power jack to supply 5V to provide the necessary juice to the chip. If you supplied 5v to GPIO output pin then you may or may not have burnt the chip but for sure you burnt the arduino board ,technically its power control system. So i think it'll be better buying a new board rather then fixing it.But i salute your attempts.

Comment: Thank you bro..I appreciate that. And I wont make such mistakes from next time